# Get output filename in Bash Script

Tags: bash

I would like to get just the filename (with extension) of the output file I pass to my bash script:

```
a=$1
b=$(basename -- "$a")
echo $b #for debug
if [ "$b" == "test" ]; then
    echo $b
fi
```

If i type in:

```
./test.sh /home/oscarchase/test.sh > /home/oscarchase/test.txt
```

I would like to get:

```
test.txt
```

in my output file but I get:

```
test.sh
```

How can I procede to parse this first argument to get the right name ?

Comment: It's not an argument, it's not something your script has access to, it's a feature of the shell your script is running in.

Comment: How can you get anything in your output? `test.sh != test`

Comment: I forgot to put my debug echo before the if

Comment: Maybe you shouldn't do that at all? Why are you doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finding out the name of the file that is opened on file descriptor 1 (standard output) is not something you can do directly in `bash`; it depends on what operating system you are using. You can use `lsof` and `awk` to do this; it doesn't rely on the `proc` file system, and although the exact call may vary, this command worked for both Linux and Mac OS X, so it is at least somewhat portable.

```
output=$( lsof -p $$ -a -d 1 -F n | awk '/^n/ {print substr($1, 2)}' )
```

Some explanation:

- `-p $$` selects open files for the current process
- `-d 1` selects only file descriptor 1
- `-a` is use to require both `-p` and `-d` apply (the default is to show all files that match *either* condition
- `-F n` modifies the output so that you get one line per field, prefixed with an identifier character. With this, you'll get two lines: one beginning with `p` and indicating the process ID, and one beginning with `n indicating the file name of the file.
- The `awk` command simply selects the line starting with `n` and outputs the first field minus the initial `n`.

Comment: A really good solution indeed! I would add that for Windows one might probably use [handle](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896655.aspx) instead of Unix-specific `lsof`.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
 #!/bin/bash

 output=$(readlink /proc/$$/fd/1)
 echo "output is performed to \"$output\""
```

but please remember that this solution is system-dependent (particularly for Linux). I'm not sure that `/proc` filesystem has the same structure in e.g. FreeBSD and certainly this script won't work in bash for Windows.

Ahha, FreeBSD obsoleted procfs a while ago and now has a different facility called [procstat](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?procstat). You may get an idea on how to extract the information you need from the following [screenshot](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tour/freebsd-8/19.png.html). I guess some [awk-ing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK) is required :)